# Excel Macro http GET won't connect to internet

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a short macro [below] to test a GET call. This macro works fine for several people that have tested it, however one person (using same version of excel - 2013) is getting a timeout error. I have allowed Excel to connect to the internet in settings, and have enabled macros. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Dim result As String
URL = "http://www.google.com"
With objHTTP
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    .send ("")
End With
```

Comment: is there a proxy server in between? That would explain the effect that one user gets a timeout. I'm not sure how to configure the proxy for XMLHTTP as I always use WinHttpRequest object. There you have a setProxy method. Not sure if the XML request object has the same

Comment: Check the ethernet cable is plugged in (sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: Try removing the `("")` after the send command it isn't needed and will cause an unnecessary evaluation of a blank string - it shouldn't be the cause of the issue but won't hurt to try. On a further note, everything you've described points towards it being an issue with the user's PC and not the code - in which case there's probably not a lot for us to advise on here...

Comment: There isn't a proxy in between. I had tried using WinHttpRequest to start, but that didn't work either. I also was thinking it may be an issue with the PC itself. I did a restore back to two weeks ago (when it was working fine), but that didn't help either. Due to this, I'm not sure that re-installing the OS will make any difference, but I can try.

Answer (score 0):

Change object type: Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Hope this help!

Comment: If I change the object type to this I get an error "access is denied" on all computers tested on.

Comment: Same idea but use `Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")` The "Microsoft" namespace is deprecated and "XMLHTTP" is a synonym for the older version from MSXML2 v3.0. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764622(v=vs.85).aspx) for the ProgID list